# Difference between running a browser in headless vs browser

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, browser, bots

I'm wondering what the difference is between running a browser in headless mode vs a regular windowed browser. Specifically, if the browser is run using Selenium, how would website's security system know if the browser is being run from headless, even if the user-agent is specified to something standard like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36`?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if a person is using your site versus an automated bot driven by selenium? Is so you really need to investigate using captcha system of some sort.

Comment: See [@DebanjanB's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb) answer! it's very detailed...

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'm trying to see why using headless, with all the appropriate user-agent modifications, doesn't work (I get blocked), and when I don't use headless, I can connect and make multiple requests to the site in Selenium. If the difference is only the GUI, then why could this be a problem?